# Divide range(len(dataframe[column])) and not the values?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, divide

This may be a really simple question for you guys, I tried searching for this question but I think I'm wording it wrong, I can't find what I'm trying to do.

Ok, so, I have a dataframe with a size (9652, 5). I am trying to divide 9652 by 3600 but NOT the values in the columns.

I tried

```
attempt1 = range(len(df['columnA'])) / 3600
```

but I'm getting

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'range' and 'int'

Let me know if I need to add in more information. I'm using pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range()` returns a sequence of numbers from 0 to `len(<DataFrame object>)`. I think what you want to do is `df.shape[0]/3600` which will give you `number of rows/3600`.

[Relevant pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html#pandas.DataFrame.shape)